# Canonical answer for "can I message X about Y"?

Tags: discussion

I recently made a rather misguided attempt to make a canonical answer for all of the questions that take this form.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/192370/can-i-contact-x-person-about-y?noredirect=1#comment519890_192370

Apologies, I was unaware of the process by which this is usually managed.

Do we think this needs a canonical answer? If so, what should the canonical answer be?

---

It's worth noting that I make a huge distinction between "can I" and "should I", this question only concerns the former. While the latter would, in my opinion, have broadly the same answer, that does have some more nuance that would make a canonical answer far harder.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:** My personal view is that you should keep thinking, you may be on to something here. But, I don't think the proposed canonical question and answer is the right one as-written.

**Longer answer...**

> These questions all boil down to the same thing. Can I contact this person about this thing?

I agree there are (to paraphrase one amazing comment from several years ago) many questions on that site that say "How do I tell Joe I don't want to wibble anymore?" and the answer is always "Just say: hey Joe, I want to stop wibbling!". The trouble is, there are also many questions that don't fit the pattern. For example: "How do I tell my student that they are terrible and should drop out of grad school?" seems like it matches the pattern, but it actually doesn't.

So, trying to come up with a one-size-fits all answer is fraught. It may be possible to come up with a canonical question here, but I think it would have to be narrower than the one in your title.

> I make a huge distinction between "can I" and "should I"

This is one option for making the question narrower, but I don't think it's a good one. While the questions are different, the intent of the asker is usually the same. If the question is "Can I ask Steven Weinberg to review my physics homework?", saying "you *could* do that..." would not be terribly helpful, even if technically correct.

Finally, note that we already have [How should I phrase an important question that I need to ask a professor?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/90725/how-should-i-phrase-an-important-question-that-i-need-to-ask-a-professor). This could be viewed as another attempt to identify a narrower version of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your point about "the intent of the asker is usually the same". I feel like "can I" implies whether it's acceptable within the confines of academia to email someone about something. The answer to which is basically always yes. Whereas "should I" takes into account whether or not that's the best approach for whatever the reason they want to make contact.

Comment: Steven Weinberg passed away last year, so it might not be technically correct.

Comment: Darn! All the “household name” physicists I can think of have passed away….

Comment: I said last year, but 2021 is no longer last year... Anyway, yeah,   it's hard to think of household names.

Comment: If you pare this down to "Can I contact *a professor* about ..." then the vast majority are covetable with a canonical answer.

Comment: Could be. In that case, I think we'd have to list the most common cases and discuss them one-by-one; I doubt we could give a useful answer that merely gave high-level principles. I personally am not sure we want to go down the road of making a massive canonical Q with dozens of sub-questions, but maybe I am in the minority.

Answer (score -2):

My two pence is that, yes, this needs a canonical answer. This is because there is one simple answer that covers every scenario that I can think of. Although, I'd happily be proven wrong. That answer is:

> Yes, you can contact any person, about anything, for any reason, at
> any time.
>
> Just be nice, polite, and avoid being demanding. They are under no
> obligation to answer you.
>
> The obvious exception of this is when you're not supposed to be able
> to work out who the person you want to contact is. Don't go trying to
> break anonymous review.

Comment: "Dear advisor: I'd like to take two years off to tour the world. I assume you will keep paying me." "Dear advisor: My medical records are attached. Please keep my therapist's comments in mind when interacting with me." "Dear Terrence Tao: I cannot exactly understand. What is a _derivative_?" "Dear professor: Could you please give me an A in the course? I will pay you whatever you like." None of these e-mails are impolite or demanding, but some are ill-advised and should not be sent. For an actual example, see [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/131743).